# Had a vector v, multiplied a rotation matrix by v, and got v back - what's the geometric meaning of this?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, transformation, rotations

So I'm doing some review for a class I have, going over some linear algebra and I don't remember a lot about rotation. Here's what's up:

I constructed a rotation matrix to transform vector components from respect with $\lt \hat x,\hat y,\hat z \gt$ to respect with $\lt \hat u,\hat v, \hat w \gt$ (where $\hat u = \lt 6/7, -3/7, 2/7 \gt, \hat v = \lt 2/7, 6/7$, $3/7 \gt$, and $\hat w = \lt -3/7,6/7,3/7 \gt$).

This is the rotation matrix I obtained:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \hat u \cdot \hat x & \hat u \cdot \hat y & \hat u \cdot \hat z \\
        \hat v \cdot \hat x & \hat v \cdot \hat y & \hat v \cdot \hat z \\
        \hat w \cdot \hat x & \hat w \cdot \hat y & \hat w \cdot \hat z \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \left(\frac{6}{7}\right) & \left(\frac{-3}{7}\right) & \left(\frac{2}{7}\right) \\
    \left(\frac{2}{7}\right) & \left(\frac{6}{7}\right) & \left(\frac{3}{7}\right)\\
    \left(\frac{-3}{7}\right) & \left(\frac{-2}{7}\right) & \left(\frac{6}{7}\right)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then I find the new components of several vectors by vector-matrix multiplication. The one vector that caused me problems was vector $v = \lt 2,-2,-2 \gt$. This is what I did:
$$A * v=v'$$
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
    \left(\frac{6}{7}\right) & \left(\frac{-3}{7}\right) & \left(\frac{2}{7}\right) \\
    \left(\frac{2}{7}\right) & \left(\frac{6}{7}\right) & \left(\frac{3}{7}\right)\\
    \left(\frac{-3}{7}\right) & \left(\frac{-2}{7}\right) & \left(\frac{6}{7}\right)
        \end{bmatrix} 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 \\
        -2 \\
        -2 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 \\
        -2 \\
        -2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus I found that $v=v'$.

My question is this: I don't understand what this means geometrically. I'm having trouble thinking of how I would conceptualise this rotation.

Is $v'$ in the same location as $v$? which was my initial reaction, but that doesn't seem right, since I changed the old components to new components with the rotation matrix. Does any one have any tips to lead me in the right direction to conceptualise this, because I am well and truly stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this means geometrically is that $v$ lies on the axis about which the rotation matrix $A$ rotates other points in $\Bbb R^3$. If we try to rotate any point lying on that axis, then we get back the same point after applying the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this, the earth is rotating, but the poles stay stationary.

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically, the answer by AOrtiz is pretty much spot on. Your rotation matrix doesn't rotate just arbitrarily, it rotates *about some line,* and things on that line get fixed.

You can notice quite readily that by linearity, this is true fore evry vector on the line spanned by $v$, and so this is the simplest example of an *eigenvector* of a linear map.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors

http://setosa.io/ev/eigenvectors-and-eigenvalues/

You should definitely try exploring this latter page to feel your way around this new concept. It is quite important in not just linear algebra, but throughout mathematics.